# How to delete annotations in PDF file using PDFBox

Tags: java, annotations, comments, highlight, pdfbox

I would like to remove all the existing annotations in the PDF file. I could not find any direct method or API in PDFBox Annotaions API.  Please provide any pointers to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have a PDPage object, just do this:

```
pdPage.setAnnotations(null);
```

Here's the full code for the 1.8.* versions of PDFBox:

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFilename), null);
List<PDPage> pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages)
{ 
    pdPage.setAnnotations(null);
}
document.save(new File(...));
document.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For 3.0.0-alpha3 version of PDFBox, this is now:

```
try (PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(inputPdf))) {
  PDPageTree pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
  for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages) { 
    pdPage.setAnnotations(new ArrayList<PDAnnotation>());
  }
  document.save(new File(outputPdf));
  document.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```